# rails update_all returns unknow column * in field list

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I have this migration task:

```
owner = Owner.first
Factory.update_all(original_owner: owner)
```

It returns an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'factories.original_owner' in 'field list': UPDATE `factories` SET `factories`.`original_owner` = 1)
```

I'm pretty sure the column is there. A migration to create that column was run successfully and I checked in console.

I am able to run the following task:

```
Factory.all.each { |c| c.update(original_employee: c.employee) }
```

However, that takes long time since it traverse the whole table. I would like to optimize the migration a bit by using `update_all` since there are many factories owned by the same owner.

Any information/clue is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Each `factory` is owned by an `owner`. An `owner` can be a `person`, `bot` or `nil`. To optimize the migration, the factories are divided into 3 groups:

- factories owned by `nil` which can be skipped
- factories owned by `person` which we can use `each` and `update` to update the original owner field
- factories owned by `bot` which we can use `update_all`

`update_all` requires to call `id` explicitly on the owner, which is `bot`. This causes `nil` headache in the case `bot` is not created in the database yet. Since `nil.id` throws an exception and breaks the program.

Issue: we use CircleCI to run test. This does not have test database yet so `bot` is `nil`. If I `rails db:seed` it requires `rails db:migrate` but `rails db:migrate` throws `nil` exception :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Factory.update_all(original_owner_id: owner.id)
```

EDIT: One of my senior colleagues come up with a better version:

```
Factory.where.not(owner: nil).update_all('original_owner_id = owner_id')
```

customised for our case:

```
Factory.where.not(owner: [nil, 0]).update_all('original_owner_id = owner_id')
```

since the query (`Factory.where.not(owner: [nil,0]).to_sql`) looks for `owner_id`

Comment: THIS saves my life !

Comment: can I ask you something more, i would like to be able to do
`Factory.update_all(original_owner: owner)` since that probably would protect from `nil` headache (the current method `owner.id` suffers from `nil` exception). Can I ask why in the `each` method, I can use `owner` object instead of calling `owner.id`?

Comment: Sure - when you call `update_all` you execute a raw SQL query - whatever you're updating has to match a column name in your database. When a factory belongs to an owner, in essence it has an owner_id column in the database. While rails knows that updating the owner really means updating the owner_id, SQL can't figure it out

Comment: The thing is, to optimize the migration, I can use `update_all`, and use the same owner `bot` for all these companies created by bot. However, technically it can happen that `bot` is nil (for example, in test database), and calling `owner.id` breaks the code. Somehow `each` and `update` escape the `nil` headache, do you have a suggestion on a way out?

Comment: Can you edit this question with your full migration code please

Comment: thanks for your help so far, it is my company's private repo though. anyway, i should raise error when `bot` is `nil`.

Comment: I only ask to see the code as I didn't really understand how you can have different bots / owners when you're updating every Factory in your database - if you run that again with a different owner it will overwrite the same records as before

Comment: If you're iterating through owners, then you can call `next unless owner && owner.id`

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me so far. You give information that helps to clarify more. Can I ask you a further question? I added information in the question, would you mind having a look?

Comment: Sorry but it's next to impossible to guess how you're performing the iterations in your code without seeing it - do you have an array of owners/bots/nil that you're iterating through? Or are they stored in another class?

Comment: hmm.. you might be able to go with `Factory.update_all(original_owner_id: owner.id) if owner && owner.id`

Comment: hey, one of my colleagues come up with a better version for our case. some sql is put in with the rails syntax. i edited your answer. so now there is no need to distinguish between `bot` and `person` anymore. do you think it is good? or can still be better optimized?